# How do I set a conditional in grok/logstash for when there is a upstream response and not

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

How do I set a conditional in logstash with the grok filter for when there is upstream response and when there is not.

I want to use this when there is.

```
 match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}  %{NUMBER:request_time:float} %{NUMBER:upstream_time:float}" }
```

When there is no response.

```
match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}  %{NUMBER:request_time:float}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}  %{NUMBER:request_time:float}( %{NUMBER:upstream_time:float})?" }
```

Should work! The ? by the field means that it is optional. Make sure to include that the space before it is optional, either by `( )?%{NUMBER:upstream_time:float}?` or by grouping it with upstream_time `( %{NUMBER:upstream_time:float})?`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [conditionals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals):

```
if [message] =~ /\d+\s+\d+$/ {
  grok {
     match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}  %{NUMBER:request_time:float} %{NUMBER:upstream_time:float}" }
  }
} else {
  grok {
     match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}  %{NUMBER:request_time:float}" }
  }
}
```

The regex `\d+\s+\d+$` check at the end of string (with the `$` anchor) the presence of two groups of digits (`\d`) of any size (`+`) separated by any number of whitespace (`\s+`).